# Why does Allah need to know

Tags: allah

Allah is all-knowing, then why in Quran 3:140-3:142 Allah tests us so that he can Aleem(know) our character?

Comment: I might be interpreting this wrong, but are you trying to ask why Allah tests us to see whether we will end up in hell or heaven? But if Allah already knows our fate, so why does he test us then?

Comment: https://youtu.be/yh0-kuMZbio